# Proof of Uniform Convergence of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Suppose K is compact and ${f_n}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on K which converges pointwisely to a continuous function f(x), and $f_n(x)\geq f_{n+1}(x)$ for all x  $\in$ K and n $\in$ N. Show $f_n \rightarrow  f$ uniformly.

My thoughts:

To prove uniform convergence I think we should use the definition(epsilon delta). But I'm not sure how to use other conditions.  I was trying to  combine "uniform 
 continuous" and "pointwise  convergence" but it didn't work.

Comment: $f_n(x)\ge f_{n+1}(x)$  may not be enough, since $f_n(x)\to -\infty$ is not ruled out.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2541875/prove-f-n-k-converges-uniformly-on-compact-sets

Comment: @herbsteinberg $f_n \to f$, and $f$ is continuous on $K$, so that will not happen.

Comment: Example: $K=[0,1]$ and $f_n(x)$ defined as follows $f_n(x)=\frac{-1}{x}$ for $x\gt \frac{1}{n}$ and $f_n(x)=-n$ for $0\le x\lt \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Then $f(0) = -\infty$, so $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: @user284331 Thank you so much! I think that is the answer I'm trying to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is the Dini’s Theorem. You can see this lecture note: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m321/dini.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much!